# i imported the webdrive module but it doesnt have the needed methods

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 import time
 input_id = 'pstMsg'


 browser = webdriver.Firefox()
 browser.get('https://gmail.com')
 user_field = browser.find_element('identifierId')
 user_field.send_keys('ilovecats@mail.com')


 next_btn = browser.find_element("VfPpkd-RLmnJb")
 next_btn.click()
```

And this is what im getting:

```
 File "C:\Users\79384\Desktop\Новая папка\web.py", line 11, in <module>
    user_field = browser.find_element('identifierId')
  File "C:\Users\79384\.virtualenvs\Новая_папка-n-B8lxvb\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 857, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\79384\.virtualenvs\Новая_папка-n-B8lxvb\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\79384\.virtualenvs\Новая_папка-n-B8lxvb\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: unknown variant `identifierId`, expected one of `css selector`, `link text`, `partial link text`, `tag name`, `xpath` at line 1 column 24
```

As I see it, the problem is that I need a `find_element_by_id` and `by_class_name`  but I don't have this in optional. I just cannot use it.

Comment: The problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use the `BY` class to determine how to find your desired HTML element.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

find_element(By.ID, "id")
find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class name")
```

You can find more about it in [this link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)